# How does block-scope in JavaScript work under the hood?

Tags: javascript, scope

Any search online or on YouTube for either:

1. The difference between `let`, `const` and `var` in JavaScript
2. JavaScript scope explained

...will undoubtedly mention how `let` and `const` are block-scoped whereas `var` is function-scoped. This makes sense to me, but none of the resources I've found get into what's actually happening under the hood to make something like block-scoping possible. As I understand, each new function invocation creates a new execution context which is placed onto the call stack, and an execution context contains a variable object which in turn contains properties corresponding to the variables defined inside that function. But since a block isn't a function (and I imagine doesn't create a new execution context), how does the block have an awareness as to what's defined inside of it? Is it some sort of IIFE like functionality happening?

Comment: The engine simply opens a new scope for a “block”. When the “block” ends, so does the scope. It works effectively equivalently to a function scope otherwise (imagine a “function block” is that makes the equivalency more clear). The execution context is not the same as a (block) scope; no need to impose such a rule.

Comment: Anyway, all of this is covered in-depth in the ECMA Script specification (that answers should reference). Since at least ES6 the semantic rules are (sometimes painfully) declared in line-by-line operating instructions.

Answer (score 0):

There are three Execution Contexts to execute their code in Javascript.

1. Global EC
2. Function EC
3. Eval EC (deprecated)

Thus,
you still use Global Execution Context with block scope, but the lexical environment will be updated to resolve the bindings. So, the block have an awareness as to what's defined inside of it.